# Embed characters in component labels

Tags: actionscript-3, encoding, radio-button

I have the following code:

```
var tf:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
tf.font = "arial";

aRButton.textField.antiAliasType = "advanced";
aRButton.setStyle("textFormat", tf);
aRButton.setStyle("embedFonts", true);
```

When i run this i get antialias on my radiobutton but the Swedish characters å, ä and ö disappears. Is there a way to manually embed these characters?

Comment: You'll have to show the code where you're setting the text.

Comment: I'm setting the text manually inside of flash. No code. Right now i have solved it by embedding the whole .ttf-file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to create a .css file by [Flex Style Explorer](http://examples.adobe.com/flex2/consulting/styleexplorer/Flex2StyleExplorer.html) and insert it into the code